# Flutter - listview.builder automatically jump to index 15 after index 4 causing an out of bound error

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview

i'm working on a listview taking object from api.
The api response the correct data, and the following ListView take the correct data (checked on debug mode) but after index 4 it goes automatically at index 15 causing an outofbound ex.

```
ListView.builder(
   scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
   shrinkWrap: true,
   itemCount: state.works.length,
   itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return WorkCard(
         work: state.works[index],
      );
   },
),
```

my bloc event:

```
on<OnHomePageLoading>(
      (event, emit) async {
        var response = await apiService.apiWorkGetLastWorksPost();

        if (response.body!.statusCode == Global.ResponseStatusCode.Ok.value) {
          emit(
            state.copyWith(
              status: HomeStatus.loaded,
              works: response.body?.data,
            ),
          );
        } else {
          emit(
            state.copyWith(
              status: HomeStatus.fail,
            ),
          );
        }
      },
    );
```

and my Page:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: const DrawerShared(),
      appBar: const AppBarShared(),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.explore),
              label: AppLocalizations.of(context)!.discover),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.menu_book),
              label: AppLocalizations.of(context)!.myLibrary),
        ],
      ),
      body: BlocProvider(
        create: (context) => HomePageBloc()
          ..add(
            OnHomePageLoading(),
          ),
        child: BlocListener<HomePageBloc, HomePageState>(
          listener: (context, state) {},
          child: Center(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.2,
                    child: Card(
                      elevation: 10,
                      child: FittedBox(
                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                        child: ClipRRect(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                          child: Image.network(
                              'https://c1.wallpaperflare.com/preview/127/366/443/library-book-bookshelf-read.jpg'),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: Container(
                            margin:
                                const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 20.0),
                            child: const Divider(
                              color: Colors.black,
                              height: 36,
                            )),
                      ),
                      Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.lastNews),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Container(
                          margin:
                              const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 10.0),
                          child: const Divider(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            height: 36,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  BlocBuilder<HomePageBloc, HomePageState>(
                    buildWhen: (previous, current) =>
                        current.status == HomeStatus.loaded,
                    builder: (context, state) {
                      return Container(
                        child: state.status == HomeStatus.loading
                            ? const Center(
                                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                              )
                            : SingleChildScrollView(
                                physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                                child: BlocBuilder<HomePageBloc, HomePageState>(
                                  buildWhen: (previous, current) =>
                                      previous.works != current.works,
                                  builder: (context, state) {
                                    return Column(
                                      children: [
                                        ListView.builder(
                                          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                                          shrinkWrap: true,
                                          itemCount: 4,
                                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,
                                              int index) {
                                            return WorkCard(
                                              work: state.works[index],
                                            );
                                          },
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    );
                                  },
                                ),
                              ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

If I set manually the itemCount property to 4 it will display correctly 4 of the 10 object.
Any advice?

PS: I dont know if it does matter but I'm using Bloc to manage state

Comment: _"If I set manually the itemCount property to 4 it will display correctly 4 of the 10 object"_ This indicates that the problem is in how the state is updated. Can you show more code that is related to updating the state? You can also try printing the state every time it updates

Comment: i edited the post to add more info